# Вывод даных из MySql есть нюанс

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

В базу (в одну из таблиц) заносяться имена людей....
Мне нужно эти имена вивести НО некоторие из имен повторяются:

```
 1. Саша
 2. Маша
 3 .Дима
 4. Маша
 5. Настя
```

Как видите им' я Маша повторяется 2 раза у меня в базе ето и другие имена могут и по 100 раз повторяться....
Мне нужно вивести все имена только один раз... тоесть если им' я Маша уже виводилось то больше его не выводим!
Каждое из имен должно быть только в одном экземпляре..
Исходя из примера выше должно выйти так:

```
 1. Саша
 2. Маша
 3. Дима
 4. Настя
```

Кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: используйте `select DISTINCT name from table`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT(field) AS field FROM table_name;